# Hi. what chinese or Mandarin word sounds phonetically like the word omniyat

Tags: phonology

what chinese or Mandarin word sounds phonetically like the word omniyat. And what is the meaning of that chinese word?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to ask, are you looking for a phonetic translation like @Conifers has provided, or are you looking for an existing word that sounds like "omniyat" perhaps because you heard it?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want it to be phonetically same, I would recommend 欧美亚特/欧尼亚特。

Answer (score 0):

I just checked that omniyat is the real estate management company in Dubai, I suppose you may want to get a proper Chinese name for translation or propaganda?

Here provide some opinions for your reference :D

- **歐米亞**: 歐 is Europe, 米 is America, 亞 is Asia. Maybe the company may want to expend market to another country in future?
- **奧你雅**: 奧 is profound or deeply, 你 is you, 雅 is elegant, graceful or stylish. Maybe the company could let you to find something unique or fashion houses or properties?

Comment: 米 does not mean America, I think you mean 美 as in 美国 - it literally translates as "beautiful country".